# Animating arrows across with the correct delay?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have 3 arrows pointing right like this:

[image] [image] [image]

I'm trying to do an animation where the first one fades in, a delay, the second one fades in, a delay, and the third one fades in, a delay and round and round they go.

I have done the following but it doesn't run so smooth.

I wanted it to look like it's a flashing set of 3 arrows pointing right as in "go here" so to speak.

```
       function animate() {
           $('.left').fadeIn(300).delay(250).fadeOut(250);
           $('.middle').delay(300).fadeIn(250).fadeOut(250);
           $('.right').delay(400).fadeIn(200).fadeOut(200);
            }
       animate();
       setInterval(animate, 1000);
```

Any tweaks to make this look the way it should with the correct delays?

Edit: Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Jvn4F/

Comment: CSS Transitions will work better here than jQuery `.animate()`. Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: Need it cross browser compatible though, instead of just for modern browsers. Will provide a jsfiddle in 2 minutes. Thanks

Comment: @Mooseman: http://jsfiddle.net/Jvn4F/

Comment: I posted an answer. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution uses CSS3 Keyframes: http://jsfiddle.net/Jvn4F/2/

CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes animate {
 0%{
   opacity: 0;
 }
40%{
   opacity: 0;
}
100%{
   opacity: 1;
 }
}
#arrows {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:220px;
    left:300px
}
#arrows .arrow{
    background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRwtw.png) no-repeat;
    height:49px;
    width:40px;
    float:left;
    opacity: 0;
}
#arrows .arrow.show{
    -webkit-animation-name: animate;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

JS:

```
$(".left").addClass('show');
setTimeout(function(){
    $(".middle").addClass('show');
}, 500);
setTimeout(function(){
    $(".right").addClass('show');
}, 1000);
```

---

This solution uses jQuery for animations: http://jsfiddle.net/Jvn4F/3/

jQuery:

```
function animate() {
    $('.left').fadeTo(500, 1).delay(500).fadeTo(500, 0);
    $('.middle').delay(250).fadeTo(500, 1).delay(500).fadeTo(500, 0);
    $('.right').delay(500).fadeTo(500, 1).delay(500).fadeTo(500, 0);
}
setInterval(animate, 2000);
```

CSS:

```
#arrows{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:220px;
    left:300px
}
#arrows .arrow{
    background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRwtw.png) no-repeat;
    height:49px;
    width:40px;
    float:left;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Because `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` removes the element from the DOM, it's slower and because of `float:left` it causes `.middle` and `.right` to shift over once `.left` or `.middle` has faded out.

---

It should be taken into account that either method (because of the JS `setTimeout` or `setInterval`) can become incorrectly timed. For some uses, (as seen with ajax loader icons) an animated gif may be better than trying to animate multiple smaller images.

Comment: You're an absolute champion! Looks incredible!! :)

Comment: If you leave the arrows for a minute or two and then watch them, you'll notice that they start messing up :/ I'm using your JQuery version. Any fix for that?